# Symfony2: home page displayed properly with /app_dev.php but not with /app.php

Tags: php, symfony, url-routing

I have a home page located at `/`, defined in the `DefaultController`. It renders a Twig tempate.

When I run the application with http://localhost:8000/app_dev.php/, the home page is displayed.

When I run the application with http://localhost:8000/app.php/, I get the typical:

```
Welcome to Symfony 2.8.0-DEV
Your application is ready to start working on it at: /
What's next?
Read Symfony documentation to learn
...
```

message. How can I get `app.php` to display the home page?

When I browse http://localhost:8000/ I get:

> The requested resource / was not found on this server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear the cache to apply changes.

```
$ php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

Source : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/usage.html